# What exactly does it mean to "send a transformation from the child to the parent frame"?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, transformations, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*First of all, I would like to say that I have some background in computer graphics (e.g., I know what homogenous transformations, etc., are). So, please, do not explain to me what matrix multiplications are.*

---

I have a question regarding the `sendTransform` method of the class [TransformBroadcaster](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html#transformbroadcaster).

The documentation says:

> Broadcast the transformation from tf frame child to parent on ROS topic "/tf".

So, e.g., suppose we subscribe to the topic `/turtle1/pose` and, in the callback, we use `sendTransform`, for example

```
def _send_pose_transform(self, pose):
    br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()

    translation = (pose.x, pose.y, 0)
    rotation = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, pose.theta)

    br.sendTransform(translation, rotation, rospy.Time.now(),
                        self.turtle_name, self.parent_frame)
```

I have at least two questions.

The last two arguments of `sendTransform` are the child and parent frames. Can either the child or the parent frames be different than the frame of the object associated with the topic I subscribed to (i.e. `/turtle1/pose`), i.e. can the child or the parent frames be a frame which is not the local frame of `turtle1`? I suppose the answer is "yes", given that I don't see why this use case should be "forbidden".

Now, my actual questions/doubts.

What exactly does it mean to **send a transformation from the child to the parent frame**, in this case? Let's now assume that `tf` keeps track of the local frames of the child and the parent objects. Does "send a transformation from the child to the parent frame" actually mean that `tf` sends e.g. a homogenous matrix representing the transformation (i.e. rotation and orientation) of a point in the local frame of the child to a point in the local frame of the parent, or is it vice-versa, or something else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288406/what-exactly-does-it-mean-to-%22send-a-transformation-from-the-child-to-the-parent-frame%22?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit:

> Does "send a transformation from the child to the parent frame" actually mean that `tf` sends e.g. a homogenous matrix representing the transformation (i.e. rotation and orientation) of a point in the local frame of the child to a point in the local frame of the parent, or is it vice-versa, or something else?

<del>I would say this is more what the various `transformX(..)` methods in TF do. The `TransformBroadcaster` really only updates the transformation matrices that you refer to (but they're not encoded as matrices, but as separate `Vector3` and `Quaternion`).</del>

re-reading your question you might actually be saying the same as I was. The `TransformBroadcaster` is not about points, but the transformation matrices themselves. If that is what you were describing, then yes, that is what it is doing. The `transformX(..)` methods in TF(2) then use those to do the actual transformation of points between those frames.

---

Could this be a misinterpretation / misquote of the docs? "Broadcasting" is the word used in the docs. This just means: sending a msg to all who are/will listen. "Sending to" implies there is some unidirectional transfer going on. TF does not send anything "from X to Y" (well, the `TransformBroadcaster` does, but at a different level perhaps).

The example you show just broadcasts a single message that contains the information about a single transform "*from the child to the parent frame*". It's a piece of information that TF listeners will use to update their tree of transforms.

The "child" and "parent" are just labels (ie: names for humans), not entities in a ROS node graph (ie: nodes or similar active constructs) that receive or send any messages.

From the same docs on `TransformBroadcaster`:

> `TransformBroadcaster` is a convenient way to send transformation updates on the `"/tf"` message topic.

All the methods in this class do is send out messages ([geometry_msgs/TransformStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TransformStamped.html)) that inform listeners about a single or multiple edge(s) in the TF tree. Between each node a transformation matrix exists. For new transforms, an edge is added and the matrix attached. For existing transforms, the matrix is updated.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-12**:
Sorry, I am asking about the transformation itself which is sent, not to whom or to which topic it is sent.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
I believe I touched on that with the last paragraph.

You ask about `TransformBroadcaster`. That class inherently has to do with topics and msgs, because that is what is used to broadcast this information.

"a transformation" is not a thing in TF. Transforms are broadcast, those contain ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
.. translations and rotations in separate fields (but conceptually the same as the matrix you're referring to).

So to broadcast a transform is to publish a msg that contains that information. That is then used by listeners to insert or update edges in their local view of the tree.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-12**:
@gvdhoorn Ok, thanks, it starts to make more sense. I think we should add this "verbose" but, IMHO, helpful description/explanation to the documentation of those methods so that we don't have to click a few times to infer what those methods do.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
It's all open-source. There is a good chance an update to the documentation submitted in a PR would be accepted. For TF, the sources are [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry). For TF2 [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry2).

Note that TF (not TF2) is deprecated.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-12**:
You're saying that `TransformStamped`s, which are sent, already exist, and we only update them using `sendTransform`. However, in this tutorial,  http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20frame%20%28Python%29, a new local frame is created using `sendTransform`...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
`TransformStamped` is just the msg containing the information. The internal data structure may be different. Doesn't matter, as long as the information (ie: transform) is retained.

re: new or existing: doesn't matter. Both can be done. Each broadcaster notifies listeners that it has ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
.. (potentially) new information. If the listener already knew about the transform (ie: received msgs about it earlier), then it updates its internal view of the tree. If it's new, it incorporates the new info (ie: add edge(s)).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
This reminds me of a question about two weeks ago (can't find it). The OP there also asked about "when do TF frames 'exist'".

Thing is, they don't really. It's (conceptually) just a big tree of vertices and edges with transform matrices attached (it's not really necessarily, but it helps).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
It's perfectly ok for a listener to have only a partial view of the big, global tree. It'll just mean that if you ask it to transform between frames it hasn't heard about, you'll get a `LookupException`.

If your TF tree has missing edges, that's a problem too.